# What is regex expression for a string after I use nokogiri to scrape

Tags: html, css, ruby, regex, web-scraping

I have this string and it is in an html document of 100 other names that are formatted the same:

`<li>Physical education sed<span class="meta"><ul><li>15184745922</li></ul></span>
</li>`

And I want to save 'Physical education sed under a name column and '15184745922' under a number column.

I was wondering how do you do this in Ruby.

In nokogiri I can get only the li's by doing this:

`puts page.css("ul li").text`

but then it comes out all in one word:"Physical education sed15184745922"

I was thinking regex is the way to go but I am stumped with that. 
I did split it on the li

```
    full_contact = page.css("ul li")[22]
    split_contact_on_li = full_contact.to_s.split(/(\W|^)li(\W|$)/).map(&:to_sym)
    puts split_contact_on_li
```

and I get this

```html
<
>
Physical education sed<span class="meta"><ul>
<
>
15184745922<
/
>
</ul></span>
<
/
>
```

The same number of lines will be shown for each contact_info and the name is always the third line before the span class and the number is always the 6th line. 
There is an instance where there might be an email address instead on the 6th line put not often.

So should I match the second and the third angular bracket and pull the information up to the third and fourth bracket then shove it into an array called name and number?

Comment: Instead of splitting on "li", split on "<li>".  That will leave you with ["", "Physical education sed<span class=\"meta\"><ul>", "15184745922</li></ul></span>\n</li>"] and you can just dump the first element and then split again on "<" within the array and just take the first element from the second split.

Answer (score 5):

You **shouldn't use a regex** to parse xhtml since the regex engine might mess up things, you should use a html parser instead. However, if you want to use a regex, you can use a regex like this:

```
<li>(.*?)<.*?<li>(.*?)<
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/mD4jY4/1)**

The idea behind this regex is to use capturing groups (using paretheses) to capture the content you want. So, for you sample input the match information is:

```
MATCH 1
    Group 1.    [4-26]  `Physical education sed`
    Group 2.    [53-64] `15184745922`
```

For example;

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

string = "<li>Physical education sed<span class=\"meta\"><ul><li>15184745922</li></ul></span></li>"
one, two = string.match(/<li>(.*?)<.*?<li>(.*?)</i).captures

p one   #=> "Physical education sed"
p two   #=> "15184745922"
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, I will look into the html parser.

Comment: @Tasha if you consider your question solved, don't forget to mark it as resolved. Btw, if you have already found your own answer, please post it and mark your question as resolved. This will help the community to avoid posting new answers :)

Comment: How to do that? Is there a button?

Comment: @Tasha, yes... you can find a tick button below the votes for each answer. You can check the answer you consider it answered your question

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do a regex on the string "physical education sed15184745922"? You can match on the first digit, and get back the number and the preceding text.

Comment: Well, most of the 100 entries have numbers but some have email addresses. For example "physical education sedphysed@gmail.com".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to use Ruby, but if I understand your question correctly I would take advantage of the gsub function (or Ruby's equivalent). It might not be the prettiest approach, but since we just want the text in one variable and the numbers in another, we can just replace the characters we don't want with empty values.

```
v1 = page.css('ul li').text
v2 = gsub('\d*', '', v1)
v3 = gsub('(^\d)', '', v1)
```

v1 gets the full text value, v2 replaces all numeric characters with '', and v3 replaces all alpha characters with '', giving us two new variables to put wherever we please.

Again, I don't know how to use Ruby, but in R I know that I could get all of the values from the page using the xpath you provided ("ul li") into a vector and then loop across the vector performing the above steps on each element. I'm not sure if that adequately answers your question, but hopefully the gsub function gets you closer to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your HTML parser (Nokogiri) and regular expressions together. First, use Nokogiri to traverse down to the first parent node that contains all the text you need, then regex the text to get what you need.

Also, consider using `.xpath` instead of `.css` it provides much more functionality to search and scrape for just what you want. Given your example, you could do like so:

```
page.xpath("//span[@class='meta']/parent::li").map do |i|
  i.text.scan(/^([a-z\s]+)(\d+)$/i).flatten
end

#=> [['Physical education sed', '15184745922'], ['the next string', '1234567890'], ...]
```

And now you have a two-dimensional array you can iterate over and save each pair.

This bit of xpath business: `"//span[@class='meta']/parent::li"` is doing what `.css` can't do, returning the parent node that has the text and specific children nodes you want to scrape against.